# Python - How to split column values using multiple separators

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am reading a .csv file and creating a Panda Dataframe. From this Dataframe I am fetching a value which is supposed to be a "list" item with comma separated values in it. But it comes out as a "string" item and I have to use a separator to split the values in it.

For example : I have a string variable by name "column_names" with below values

```
column_names = "First_Name, Last_Name,Middle_Name"
column_names = column_name.split(',')
```

Please note the space before the second value. So when I print this variable, I would be getting a space before the second element which will further create trouble while extracting values from this variable.

```
print(column_names)
```

> ['First_Name', ' Last_Name', 'Middle_Name']

In order to overcome this, if I keep separator to have a space along with actual separator (here it will be ', ' ), then the values are not getting splitted properly as seen below

```
column_names = "First_Name, Last_Name,Middle_Name"
column_names = column_names.split(', ')
print(column_names)
```

> ['First_Name', 'Last_Name,Middle_Name']

Notice the space to the right of comma while splitting. Using this separator, I am able to get only two values instead of three values.

**My problem is the variable may contain comma separated values along with a space to the left or right of the comma or there may be no space at all. I have to handle all the cases with a single command (if possible). Something like providing multiple separator values while splitting.**

For example : column_names.split(','|', '|' ,').

Not sure whether there is any as such but any pointers to this will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common issue with CSVs. Fortunately, you can nip this in the bud, simply by reading your CSV properly, so you don't have to do all this unnecessary post-processing later.

When reading your dataframe with `read_csv`, pass a regex to `sep`\ `delimiter` -

```
df = pd.read_csv(..., sep='\s*,\s*', engine='python')
```

Now, `df.columns` should be a list of strings.

Comment: Thanks @coldspeed . This helps . But just for knowledge. Lets leave pandas. Inorder to split a string variable with multiple separators can I use any of the answers mentioned here ?

Comment: @JKC No. You will have to use regular expressions in that case.

Comment: @coldspeed I think your answer should contain pd.read_csv instead of pd.DataFrame

Comment: Thanks @coldspeed :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of [`skipinitialspace=True` parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',', skipinitialspace=True)
```

> **skipinitialspace** : boolean, default False
>
> ```
> Skip spaces after delimiter.
> ```

NOTE: this parameter takes care **only** of spaces **after** delimiter, so @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's answer is more generic.

Comment: By the way, does this also work if the space exists before the delimiter?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, no, it'll take care only of spaces __after__ delimiter

Comment: Oh, ok. I think that should be fine, but might just want to make it clear that `"First_Name  , Last_Name  ,Middle_Name"` for example will retain trailing spaces.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, well Galen's answer would help OP to deal with the list of columns, so it does answer the original question. BUT OP would face a next problem (spaces in values) immediately after that... ;-)

Comment: Thanks @MaxU. Good one. But I have to go with Coldspeed's answer as it is more generic.

Comment: @JKC, sure, i'd also use his solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

column_names = "First_Name , Last_Name,Middle_Name"
l = re.compile("\s*,\s*").split(column_names)
print(l)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation as to how this solves the question.

Comment: @Masudul Hasan This is good to split string variables but please explain when you provide an answer so that others users may understand easily. Thanks