# How to import ascii dat file as a float instead of string in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple ASCII dat file which I want to import into `python` as `numpy` array. The dat file (a.dat) simply looks like:

```
1.0000000e+00   2.0000000e+00

3.0000000e+00   4.0000000e+00
```

The issue I encounter is that I use the `pandas.read_table` to import the file

```
a=pd.read_table('a.dat',header=None)
```

and when I convert to the array by using `a.values`

The result is

```
array([['   1.0000000e+00   2.0000000e+00'],
       ['   3.0000000e+00   4.0000000e+00']], dtype=object)
```

The problem is that the float numbers are interpreted as strings. My actual data file is much larger than this simple matrix and thus post process of converting string to float may not be very efficient.

Strangely, I cannot even specify `dtype=np.float` as it says:

`TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'`

So is there a direct way that I can import this kind of matrix-like dat file into `numpy` float array?

Any comments and idea are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - How to split column values using multiple separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770013/python-how-to-split-column-values-using-multiple-separators)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default separator for `read_table` is TAB, not space. Just tell it to use space:

```
pd.read_table('a.dat', header=None, sep='\s')
#     0    1
#0  1.0  2.0
#1  3.0  4.0
```

Comment: I got it. Thank you! I used pd.read_table('a.dat', header=None, sep='\s+') and it works. If I only use  sep='\s'. Then it will show like 1. NaN NaN 2. I guess it is because there are multiple spaces in between.